# How do I remove unwanted OS X User Accounts?

Tags: macbook-pro

When starting my MacBook Pro I get 4 Accounts to choose from and need to choose one of them.  One of the 4 Accounts is named Guest - will keep this.  The other two are not wanted. One has Admin below it. The other has Standard below it.  The one I use is Peter with Admin below it. How to remove the two unwanted Accounts?

Comment: Since you didn't say what version of OS X is installed have a look at [OS X Mavericks: Delete a user](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH13864?locale=en_US) or [OS X Yosemite: Delete a user](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18890?locale=en_US).

Comment: Did you buy this machine second-hand? Are these the previous user's accounts? If so, you really should wipe the machine & start over. Anything purchased under the previous accounts [including the OS itself] still belong to them & you will need to enter their credentials to update anything. Otherwise… how did those accounts get there in the first place without your knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

The 'discs' you're referring to are users for your computer.

In the system preferences pane, click on a user, for example QCD in your case.

Now click on the '-' sign under 'Login Options;[image]

This should do the trick.

Comment: Thank you. removed the one that had Admin below it. But, the one that had Standard below it, i got this notice –  peter 41 secs ago   edit   
     
Unable to delete he user account QCD. An error occurred while backing up this user's home folder. –  peter just now   edit

Comment: Try deleting it without backing up the home folder.

Answer (score 1):

Below the list of current users, you will see a '+' and '-' button (just above the small padlock).

Click on the '-' button, and select one of the user accounts you want to remove..... it should be obvious what to do from that point (then repeat for the other account you want to remove).

If the padlock is in the locked position, you will need to click on the padlock, and then enter your admin password to unlock it.

(I'm on my phone so can't provide screen shots, but hope this is understandable).

Comment: Thank you. removed the one that had Admin below it.  But, the one that had Standard below it, i got this notice

Comment: Unable to delete he user account QCD. An error occurred while backing up this user's home folder.

Comment: Do you need to save the QCD users home folder? If you don't need it, delete the user account, but chose the option that says delete the users hole folder.

Comment: Thank you. Will find out more about Home Folders then decide.